# Is it safe to cast a IDispatch* into an IUnknown*, without using QueryInterface, for interprocess COM objects?

Tags: c++, com, atl, dcom, dangling-pointer

When dealing with interprocess `COM` objects, is it safe to cast a `IDispatch*` into an `IUnknown*`, without using `QueryInterface` ?

Here our `IDispatch` object comes from an other process `OtherProcess.exe`.
And a colleague of mine says that I should call `QueryInterface` on the `IDispatch` so as to get an `IUnknown`.

Currently I'm doing:

```
void CComThrowDispatch::CheckCOMAvailabilty() const
{
    IUnknown * pIUnknown = m_spDispatchDriver.p;   
    // is this line above a problem ? 
    // m_spDispatchDriver is an ATL CComDispatchDriver 
    // it handles an object instanciated in another process.
    // m_spDispatchDriver.p is of type IDispatch*

    if (pIUnknown == nullptr) return;
    bool bComObjectReachable = ::CoIsHandlerConnected(pIUnknown) == TRUE;
    if (bComObjectReachable == false)
    {
        throw MyException;
    }
}
```

My problem with his suggestion: I am dealing with cases (access violations) when the OtherProcess.exe has crashed or has been killed. It seems calling any functions like `Invoke` on the `IDispatch` that encapsulates any objects from this no longer exisiting OtherProcess.exe provokes these access violations (**EDIT:** comments and answers reveals that this latest assumption was completely false!).

That's why I'm trying to protect the application testing `::CoIsHandlerConnected(pIUnknown);` which takes an `IUnknown` as parameter.

But by calling `QueryInterface` on the `IDispatch`, like my colleague advises me to do, I am afraid to fall back in the same problem I am trying to solve: This `IDispatch` handles an object that no longer exists, and `QueryInterface` to an  `IUnknown` would just be Undefined Behaviour all the same (**EDIT** again, this assumption is also false).

Am I really wrong when I just do the cast ?
What is the common way to deal with dead interprocess `COM` objects ?

This is the begining of the definition of `IDispatch` in OAIdl.h, which is declared as deriving from `IUnknown`.

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")
IDispatch : public IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoCount( 
        /* [out] */ __RPC__out UINT *pctinfo) = 0;
```

Comment: It is *really* wrong to cast.  Calling a method on an interface from a dead server causes an RPC error, not an AVE.  You need to get RPC_E_SERVERDIED.  You need to focus on the real problem here, right now you are just making it worse.

Comment: @HansPassant That's interesting, thanks. However I have hard time understanding why it's *really wrong* to **upcast** an IDispatch, which derives from IUnknown, into a IUnknown. Could you elaborate about that ? What is the initial mistake I am doing ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland: In some cases you want/need to query `IUnknown` even though any interface derive from it and cast is available (see [Objects Must Have Identity section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), however it is not the case here in your question.

Comment: @RomanR.yes, your answer and Hans's one made me see that the access violation must come from somewhere else. But does it mean that COM is not fully C++ compatible ? **That it is broken because polymorphism is kind of not guaranteed because a cast of IDispatch into its base class is not guaranteed**. Is my wording of the problem right ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland: No, I don't think this wording is incorrect. The uncertainty comes from the fact that COM object might implement several IUnkown's, several IDispatch'es at a time, and then `QueryInterface` is not a cast - it is a method that returns a pointer, and this pointer might be or might not be implemented by the same C++ (or not C++) class. The API in questions says "give me IUnknown" and this raises the question which exactly IUnknown you should provide, and whether the one implemented as a part of IDispatch is good enough. And all mentioned is legal, not broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting `IDispatch` to `IUnknown` in C++ (like `static_cast<IUnknown*>(pDispatch)`) yields exactly the same pointer value, because `IDispatch` derives from `IUnknown`. OTOH, doing `QueryInterface` for `IID_IUnknown` on `pDispatch` *may* return a different pointer, but it's still a legit operation. In fact, this is how to get the identity of a COM object, say, to check if two interfaces are implemented by the same COM object (a hard COM rule which always work inside the same COM apartment).

That said, the proxy COM object implemented by the COM marshaller *may* be caching interfaces, so the call to `IDispatch::QueryInterface` may return `S_OK` and a valid `IUnknown` identity of the proxy, despite the remote server already went down. That is, such operation *might* not be causing an instant IPC call.

In your case, to test if the COM server is still alive and well, I'd simply call `IDispatch::GetTypeInfoCount` on the proxy object you already have. That would actually cause an IPC call (or a round-trip over the wire, if the server runs on a different host).

In case the remote server has crashed or is unavailable, you'd likely receive a `CO_E_OBJNOTCONNECTED` error (could perhaps be a different error code, but certainly not `S_OK`).

Note though, doing an extra IPC call just to check if the server is available might be a costly operation, depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should always you `QueryInterface`.

Just because you've com an `IUnknown` interface it doesn't mean you can directly cast it to `IDispatch`. COM may have given you a proxy to the underlying object, which means that the pointer has nothing to do with `IDispatch`.

Likewise, an implementation may wrap an object that implements `IDispatch` and when you call `QueryInterface` it delegates to this object. Or you may have a pointer to a COM objects that delegates to an outer `IUnknown`.

So, basically, never directly cast, even if you think it'll work, because things may change over time. Calling `QueryInterface` is rarely a performance bottleneck and therefore not worth avoiding.

Comment: I have an IDispatch* and I cast it into IUnkown*. **IDispatch derives from  IUnkown**. You're answer talks about the other way around, which I completely agree is wrong.**Downcast is dangerous**, but not upcast as far as I know. Isn't it ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland - it's still not safe. Your `IDispatch` may be a member of the overall object. By downcasting you'll see the `IUnknown` of the member, not the controlling `IUnknown` that actually represents the COM object.

Answer (score 2):

In order to detect whether the object is remote `CoIsHandlerConnected` would `QueryInterface` the argument anyway (for `IProxyManager` etc), so it does not matter whether you provide the pointer you already have, or you additionally query for `IUnknown`. Your `QueryInterface` call has not effect on the status of the remote object: whether the object is remote or not, whether remote object is dead or not - `CoIsHandlerConnected` has the same result for you regardless of your additional `QueryInterface`. Hence, there is no need to do it.

Then another note is that it is still safe to call `IDispatch::Invoke` if remote object is dead (out-of-process server crashed etc). The proxy simply returns error code without undefined behavior. That is, it looks like you don't need `CoIsHandlerConnected` at all, and if you experience access violations in context of client process, then you probably have other issues to resolve first.